# Facing "Torch not complied with CUDA enabled" when using DeOldify

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I have been trying to use DeOldify and I'm following the steps from here.
[Manual](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jantic/DeOldify/blob/master/VideoColorizerColab.ipynb#scrollTo=-T-svuHytJ-8)

Im facing two issues I'm unable to find the Runtime settings and running `from fasterai.visualize import *` yields the following error.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------    ----
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ec3d448c437f> in <module>
----> 1 from fasterai.visualize import *

~/DeOldify/fasterai/visualize.py in <module>
  5 from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
  6 from .filters import IFilter, MasterFilter, ColorizerFilter
----> 7 from .generators import gen_inference_deep, gen_inference_wide
  8 from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
  9 from scipy import misc

~/DeOldify/fasterai/generators.py in <module>
 14       return learn
 15 
---> 16 def gen_learner_wide(data:ImageDataBunch, gen_loss=FeatureLoss(), arch=models.resnet101, nf_factor:int=2)->Learner:
 17     return unet_learner_wide(data, arch=arch, wd=1e-3, blur=True, norm_type=NormType.Spectral,
 18                         self_attention=True, y_range=(-3.,3.), loss_func=gen_loss, nf_factor=nf_factor)

~/DeOldify/fasterai/loss.py in __init__(self, layer_wgts)
 10         super().__init__()
 11 
---> 12         self.m_feat = models.vgg16_bn(True).features.cuda().eval()
 13         requires_grad(self.m_feat, False)
 14         blocks = [i-1 for i,o in enumerate(children(self.m_feat)) if isinstance(o,nn.MaxPool2d)]

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in cuda(self, device)
263             Module: self
264         """
--> 265         return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
266 
267     def cpu(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _apply(self, fn)
191     def _apply(self, fn):
192         for module in self.children():
--> 193             module._apply(fn)
194 
195         for param in self._parameters.values():

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _apply(self, fn)
197                 # Tensors stored in modules are graph leaves, and we don't
198                 # want to create copy nodes, so we have to unpack the data.
--> 199                 param.data = fn(param.data)
200                 if param._grad is not None:
201                     param._grad.data = fn(param._grad.data)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in <lambda>(t)
263             Module: self
264         """
--> 265         return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
266 
267     def cpu(self):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py in _lazy_init()
160         raise RuntimeError(
161             "Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. " + msg)
--> 162     _check_driver()
163     torch._C._cuda_init()
164     _cudart = _load_cudart()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py in _check_driver()
 73 def _check_driver():
 74     if not hasattr(torch._C, '_cuda_isDriverSufficient'):
---> 75         raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
 76     if not torch._C._cuda_isDriverSufficient():
 77         if torch._C._cuda_getDriverVersion() == 0:

AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

Comment: Are you intending to use a GPU?  Do you have a GPU? Is the GPU driver properly installed?  Is it the latest driver for your GPU?  Are you doing this on a google colab instance? Did you install or build Torch with CUDA enabled?

Comment: Im doing this on MacBook Air.Im using intel integrated Graphics.Im doing this on Jupyter Notebook.I just did a `conda install pytorch -c pytorch`

Comment: The instructions and notebook you are working from assume and expect a CUDA GPU, pytorch for GPU, and CUDNN.

Comment: DeOldify author here- are you trying to just colorize images/video (as opposed to doing training)?  If so, your best bet is to use the Colabs instead (linked to on the readme in the GitHub project).  Robert Crovella is correct- you can't use your MacBook Air for this (but can use the Colabs from your laptop).

Comment: @RobertCrovella thank you sir, I realised My mistake.

Comment: @JasonAntic Thank you sir, I figured that out a lot later.and Yes I was just trying to colorise an Image.